# Xcode not selecting correct certificate while archiving App

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, provisioning-profile

I am Submitting an App to App store. when I archive my App then it successfully submitted but I got an email namely "Missing Push Notification Entitlement".. and in test flight when I tried to install the App "test-flight is currently unavailable" this message occur  then I noticed Xcode didn't selected provisioning certificate.

```
     [![Final Submission ][1]][1]
```

[image]
 What should I do to solve this issue? Please Help With suggestions.

Comment: have you selected `Team` in General Tab of Target

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati Yes

Comment: have you redownloaded profile after any changes in dev.apple? and reinstalled in xcode?

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati I also recreated and downloaded and selected in Code signing. And selected code signing identity as distribution.

Comment: Have you created app store distribution provisioning profile with push notification enable in App ID? also dev. and distribution provisioning profile. it seems to be you are using default certificated generated by xcode.

Comment: there is one way that you can create ipa using local signing assets and pray god to work well.

Comment: @AvijitNagare I have push enable in both Dev. and adhoc certificate

Comment: Restart xcode or system. then code sign

Comment: XCode is regenerating default certificate if I deleted old default certificate

Comment: my bundle name starts with in.projectname. should I change it to com.projectname?